# как убрать вывод wget

Tags: linux, bash, debian, sh, wget

> алик решил что, моя отписка от его рассылок неважна, и что можно срать мне в мыло. первичный план с ответным спамом был провален тк я тупенький и нужно поднимать сервак мыла сс доменом поэтому в дело был введён plan9 микро ддос атака от лица 10 лямов челов (серые ип имеют свои преимущества)

имеется скрипт

```
i=0
while :
do
    $i++;
    wget -nv --server-response --user-agent="STOP SEND THE SPAM ON EMAIL mail@gmail.com (attack will be stoped at evning or call +phone)(i had dismiss, also i was report)"  http://aliexpress.ru  -O /dev/null
    wget -nv --server-response --user-agent="STOP SEND THE SPAM ON EMAIL mail.com (attack will be stoped at evning or call +phone)(i had dismiss, also i was report)"  http://aliexpress.com -O /dev/null
    echo $i\r;
done
```

ну и вот вывод вгета мешает видеть скока раз был запрос, потом припаяю скорость и буду  ждать ответа
ps: мыло и номер указаны реальные , изменил для вопроса

Comment: `man wget` не помогает?

Comment: ЗЫ. Ваш «ддос» никто не заметит

Comment: @AlexeyTen моральное удовлетворение ни кто не отменял

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stderr нужно в перенаправлять, стдаут уже перенаправляется через -O.

```
.... 2> /dev/null
```

Или как говорит man wget

```
.... -o /dev/null -O /dev/null
```

Ещё с опцией `-b` можно послать больше запросов. Пока не зависнет комп)

Comment: второй вариант рабочий, так же работает вариант ` wget ....  http://aliexpress.com > /dev/null 2> /dev/null` хз почему вчера до него не додумался

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать стандартный редирект вывода.
`&> /dev/null`

```
wget -nv --server-response --user-agent="STOP SEND THE SPAM ON EMAIL mail@gmail.com (attack will be stoped at evning or call +phone)(i had dismiss, also i was report)"  http://aliexpress.ru  -O /dev/null &> /dev/null
```

Подробнее тут https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html

Comment: это первое что я попробывал,- не выходит,- вывод идёт в консоль